# CSS DIV Alignment with dynamic content

Tags: html, css

My question is about CSS and DIV tags. I have a dynamic page, and I would like one container DIV. There are two scenarios: in one case, this container DIV will just have one DIV in it, with a width of 50%, and should be centered. In the other case, there will be two DIVs in it, and they should be side by side, each taking up 50%.

I have tried float:center (using overflow: hidden on the container DIV), and that works for 1 DIV in it, but with two, they are stacked on top of each other. If I use float: left, then the 2 DIVS appear correct, but the single DIV is left aligned, not centered.

Any help on how to achieve this effectively would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div style="width:800; margin: 2px; background-color:blue">
    <div style="width:50%;  background-color:orange;">
        Text
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%; background-color:red;">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gog18gj/1/)

Comment: I started a fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/6gog18gj/1/

Comment: Don't try to CSS this. While it "may" be possible, it will not suite most standards and won't be very compatible. The best way to do this would be with some jQuery.

Comment: Code and jsFiddle copied to the question.

Comment: `style="width=50%;` is malformed, you don't use `=` within the style attribute.

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gog18gj/3/)

Comment: _"I have tried float:center"_ The possible values for `float` are: `none|left|right|initial|inherit`: [float - CSS|MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Answer (score 1):

For the two-div scenario:

```
<div style="width:800; margin: 2px; background-color:blue; display: table;">
    <div style="background-color:orange; display: table-cell;">
        Text
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:red; display: table-cell;">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Now for the one-div scenario:

```
<div style="width:800; margin: 2px; background-color:blue; display: table;">
    <div style="background-color:orange; display: table-cell;">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

In each case, the inner divs, whether there are 1 or 2, will take up a combined 100% of the outer div. Essentially, it acts like the `<table>` element without having the semantics of a `<table>`.

Comment: Don't forget to centre the parent div with `margin: 0 auto;` and put `800px` for the width, not the current `width:800;`.

Comment: But this doesnt make neither the 2 divs case nor the 1 div case centered, which I think the OP needs..

Comment: @misterManSam If you would **edit** my answer with the correct CSS, I will happily accept.

Comment: @Lal I believe with misterManSam's changes to the CSS, the inner divs will be centered.

Answer (score 1):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5vAu/85/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="divholder"> 
        <div style="background-color:orange;">DIV 1</div>
        <div style="background-color:red;">DIV 2</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.divholder div{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:auto;
    width:49%;

}
.divholder {
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
.wrapper{
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

This perfectly deals with your need..While there is only one div, the div gets centered and if two divs come then both will be equally divided and floated left.Please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5vAu/85/)..

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [chharvey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25249935/2930477), this can be achieved nicely with `display: table;`

In my example it is centered horizontally and will work with any number of columns as they will fit themselves to the full width of `div.wrap`. The columns are currently given a height of 100%, this can be adjusted.

[Have a jsBin example!](http://jsbin.com/yucaq/1/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="column">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrap { 
    display: table;
    width: 800px; 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.column {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #FF0;
}
.column:first-child {
    background: #F00;
}
```